# IFERROR formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvZyy.jpg

I kind of have a difficult question. I am currently trying to map over some data from a separate sheet onto a template/form.  Attached above is the data I am tying to map over.

Currently this is my formula on my template:

```
 =IFERROR(INDEX(STP_Data!$F$70:$F$78, IFERROR(MATCH(7443, STP_Data!$G$70:$G$78, 0), MATCH(7664, STP_Data!$G$70:$G$78, 0))), "N/A")
```

1. I need the first cell to look and see if it has '7443' and pull it
2. If it doesn't it will pull '7664'
3. I will need it to pull '7664' also on the next cell if my table has 7664
4. I also need to expand it to encompass duplicate; so like second occurrences. I have a formula for this as well:

--

```
  =IFERROR(INDEX(STP_Data!$F$70:$F$78, IFERROR(MATCH(7443, STP_Data!$G$70:$G$78, 0), AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:$10)/(STP_Data!$F$70:$G$78=7664), ROW(2:2)))), "N/A")
```

Basically: I need a way to pull '7443', '7664' and all duplicates.  Any help or point in the right direction would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Please explain with screenshots of excel

Answer (score 0):

Try this(obviously you may have to change the ranges) - you need to use these formulas on the sheet you want the information.

```
=indirect(if(or(indirect("'STP_Data!'!g2")=7664,indirect("'STP_Data!'!g2")=7443),indirect("'STP_Data!'!g2"),"N/a")
```

drag down the formula...
then just filter out the N/a's.
if you want to see the column with duplicates then do this formula at the adjacent cell and do:-

```
=indirect("'STP_Data!'!a2")   (where A2 is change to the column you want to see then drag down the formula.)
```

then you can see the duplicates at the sides of the 7664 or 7443.

Hope this at least points you in the correct direction :)